# truecallerjs bulk mobile number limit

Tags: max, limit

What is the maximum limit for truecallerjs bulk mobile numbers??

we are extracting names from mobile number data have.

I tried over 2500 number at once but error 429 was showing up which is basically request limit exceed

Answer (score 0):

In order to fulfill your request, I suggest employing multiple installation IDs for each search, limiting the number of phone numbers per request to fewer than 30. Additionally, you may consider making 5 to 6 requests per day. In the event that an installation ID expires, it would be advisable to transition to another valid ID to ensure uninterrupted access.